# Can we make controller as singleton in angularjs? And view of visited state should be same as i left?

Tags: angularjs, singleton

In my project i want that , if i change state and come back to visited state, so controller should not be reinitialize . And as well as view of that state should be same as i left.

So how we can do it in angular??

Answer (score 0):

Controllers don't act as singleton. But you can preserve state in a service/factory which behaves as singleton https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services. But keep in mind that state in service will lose after the user clicks on browser refresh button and the whole angular app will be restarted. You can use local storage/cookies if you want to keep state also between page refreshes.